# Why will Moshiach fight in wars?

Tags: messiah, army-military-war

According to Prophet Isaiah of blessed memory when Moshiach comes there will be no more wars but according to the Rambam of blessed memory one of the ways to know if somebody is Moshiach is if he fights in wars, so will Moshiach fight in wars.

Comment: Where does Isaiah say that? Does he say the wars will stop before Moshaich get here, or only after he's won a few definitive ones?

Comment: Good question. If you see the Rambam (end of the laws of kings), he is talking about the process of the arrival of the Messianic Era). First there is someone who has the potential to be the Redeemer. Then he has to perform certain acts so that you know he is definitely the Redeemer. Then the Messianic era will arrive.

Comment: Also note that the wars that the Rambam refers to are "Wars of G-d", which does not necessarily mean physical wars, it could be spiritual battles as well.